# post on Facebook through cron job

Tags: php, facebook, curl, cron, facebook-php-sdk

I try to build an facebook auto poster for the own users wall (post as user to own wall). Therefor I have to do an facebook application through `https://developers/facebook.com/apps`. After I’ve defined the `Secure Canvas URL` I wrote the code for the `index.php` of the `Secure Canvas URL` to have the ability to post messages, links or pictures to the own users wall:

```
session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('App-ID','App-Secret');

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

$path = 'path/';

$message        = file_get_contents($path . 'message.php');
$description    = file_get_contents($path . 'description.php');
$link           = file_get_contents($path . 'link.php');
$picture        = file_get_contents($path . 'picture.php');

try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

if (isset($session)) {
    try {

        // Doing a post
        if ($picture == '') {
            $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
                    'message' => $message,
                    'link' => $link,
                    'description' => $description
                )
            ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

        // Uploading a picture
        } else if ($picture != '') {
            $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(  
                    'source' => new CURLFile($picture, 'image/jpg'),
                    'message' => $message
                )
            ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
        }
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://apps.facebook.com/App-Name/');
    $auth_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email', 'publish_actions'));
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$auth_url."'</script>";
}
```

When I’m calling the `Secure-Canvas-URL/index.php` everything is working well and the post appears on my wall. So now it was the task to write a php script named `cron.php` which calls the `index.php` file above to post on my wall without calling the `Secure-Canvas-URL/index.php` directly. I’ve done that via cURL:

```
facebookLogin('email', 'password');

// Function for logging in to facebook via cURL
function facebookLogin($email, $password) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($email).'&pass='.urlencode($password).'&login=Login');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
    $page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

    // Post on facebook
    facebookPost();
}

// Function for posting content through facebook via cURL
function facebookPost() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://Secure-Canvas-URL/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    $page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

}
```

When I’m calling the php file via `http://example.com/cron.php` the post appears on my wall. So this is working well, too. Now the php script has to be run through a cron job for automatically posting:

```
* * * * * /kunden/usr/bin/wget http://example.com/cron.php
```

The cron job calls the php script successfully which I tested by sending an email each minute. The problem is that the script `cron.php` isn’t able to post on my wall when it’s running by the cron job.

I suspect that I have to receive something from facebook which happens when I’m calling the `Secure-Canvas-URL/index.php` or `http://example.com/cron.php` in my browser but not when the cron is doing that job.

Comment: You should not be using cURL to log the user into Facebook. Facebook policies forbid you from requesting the user's username/password at all, and your automated login.php accesses will eventually be noticed and blocked by a captcha. Your cron should be using access tokens and the Graph API.

Comment: And on top of that autoposting is not allowed

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you give me an example how you would do this?

Comment: @WizKid yes it is. But what would happen if facebook notice that. Probably they will close the profile and that's it.

Comment: so...you just don´t care if something is not allowed? that´s exactly why facebook has to restrict stuff all the time, because people try to abuse the system and don´t care about rules :/ - anyway, we will not discuss illegal stuff on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please enlighten me... Why is "autoposting" not allowed? And where does it say that? And if so... how does hootsuite etc get away with it? Provided it's to your own wall I don't see the problem.