# facebook – log in and posting to own wall automatically through cron

Tags: php, facebook, curl, cron, facebook-php-sdk

I'm searching for a solution where a php script called by a cron job is logging me in to facebook and posting a message to my own wall without any browser needed.

With a facebook application in combination with the facebook-php-sdk it's easy to do this job. But therefor I have to be logged in to my profile which I’m not when the cron runs.

When I'm using cURL I must do this through a browser to post the message on my wall successfully. So when cron calls the php script and cURL logs me in and calls the application to post the message, link or picture nothing happens.

All in all I nearly have the same problem like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990254/post-on-facebook-through-cron-job) described. In this post they say that it's not allowed to do this. But is it possible? And what will happen if facebook is noticing that?

Comment: Stop with the cURL nonsense – get an access token in the way you are supposed to (by following the login flow), extend it to be valid for 60 days, and use that in your cron job (and renew it when it expires).

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook SDK for PHP from developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0 . Extend short-lived access token to Long Lived access token. Save the token and use the token to log into his account when you want to login, and post to your wall. Check FB documentation: developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0 –
Read the documentation...